# Extend jQuery library when it is imported via NPM

Tags: javascript, jquery, npm

I'm trying to figure out a way to extend my jQuery library in an NPM (React) project. (I know jQuery is not a good friend of react but in this instance i really need to do so)

I'm extending my jQuery function like this:

```
(function ($) {
    $.my_function= function (parent, id) {...}
})(jQuery)
```

But how would i I call this in my react application flow? Should I create a custom component and execute it somehow from there after the `import $ from 'jquery';` gets called?